# tag a cvs merge point later based on the merging date

Tags: merge, cvs

The scenario:

I've merged the most recent version of my development branch to the head a couple of weeks ago.
I know I have to tag the merge-points but I forgot.
The head already contains a couple of features(4-5) which haven't been released yet because they are not properly tested.

Plans have changed, now I must work on a brand new feature.
This feature must be released with a subset of features from the head since we have
not enough time to test and release them all.

The question:

I've already comitted a bunch of things to the head since merging.
Is it possible to tag the merge-point of the head afterwards? If yes, HOW?
I know the date and time of the merge exactly since I've commented the first commit after merging.

My plan:

merge the desired features from the head into my most recent branch(the same that I've merged to the head).
Implement the brand new feature, test, release, merge back to head :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create tags on files given a date with `-D` on `cvs rtag`.

`$ cvs rtag -D DATE {module}`

From [Version Management with CVS](http://ftp.gnu.org/non-gnu/cvs/source/stable/1.11.23/cederqvist-1.11.23.pdf):

> -D *date* Tag the most recent revision no later than *date*.

Given the situation:

```
            tag_0     tag_1       tag_2     tag_3
------------|---------|-----------|---------|--------> TRUNK
    \
     \
      \----------------------> BRANCH
```

Let's say you want to merge modifications made from `tag_1` until `tag_3` from `TRUNK` to `BRANCH`. With a working copy in `BRANCH` branch, run this command:

`$ cvs up -d -j tag_1 -j tag_3`.

`-d` options creates new directories, if required.

Comment: you answer helped me alot by pointing into the right direction.  `cvs rtag -D "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm PM" nameOfTheProjectToTag` solved my tagging issue(the project name was missing in your example)